# What does 'treasure is tickle' mean in Philotimus?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, early-modern-english

In [Philotimus](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A07415.0001.001/1:5.2?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=treasure+is+tickle#hl1) (1583), the following passage appears on page 38:

> Among all forts of conceyted fellowes, I reuerence the Esseni∣ans, as most cōtinent in pleasures, & contented wt nifles, for they abhor ye company of women, & detest ye possession of gold & siluer. Thus Venus is wanton and euer is wanting, **treasure is tickle,** and a iuell of ieopardy, mariage marrs all, if it be out of season.

Which is basically:

> Thus Venus is wanton and ever is wanting, treasure is tickle, and a jewel of jeopardy, marriage mars all, if it be out of season.

And here's the original text:

> [image]

What does 'treasure is tickle' mean here?

I’ve found enough through my own research that I have at least a *guess* at it, which I’ll post as an answer, but I’m sure someone else might find more examples or have a more definitive/better theory as to what this could mean, and they should feel free to add it.

My first theory was that ‘tickle’ was a mistranscription of ‘fickle.’ This makes a bit of sense, as saying that fortune is fickle is a sentiment that many intellectuals enjoy espousing. But I can’t find that error repeated anywhere else in the text, and besides, all the other online versions I found have that same spelling. Even the original text isn't really that helpful in that respect in disambiguating this.

(It also seems to be a proverb, as it’s included [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionary_of_Proverbs/7PMZJqSR4sAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=tickle))

Comment: Not labeling it a typo, or an F that looks like a T, but the author is saying that treasure is **fickle**. Just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tickle* means *fickle*:

> **tickle**, **adj.** (and **adv.**)
>  <sub>Forms:  see the verb; also Middle English **tikil**, **tikul, tekil**, Middle English
> **tekyl**, **tekel**, **tykell**, 1500s **tyckyll**, 1500s–1600s **tickell**, 1700s *dialect* **tikkle**</sub>
>
> **5.** Not to be depended upon; uncertain (in fact, action, duration, etc.); unreliable; changeable, inconstant, capricious, fickle,
> ‘kittle’. Now *dialect*.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Here’s an example usage from the *OED* in your timeframe:

> <sub>1566     W. PAINTER *Palace of Pleasure* I. xiii. f. 36
>     Holde faste thy fortune, for she is tickle and can not
> bee holden against her will.</sub>

Comment: Of course the OED would have it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**My own theory:**

[This](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Studies_in_Philology/2Ts5AAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22treasure%20is%20tickle%22&dq=%22treasure%20is%20tickle%22&printsec=frontcover) snippet juxtaposes a similar construction “Tickell treasure,” and this turns out to be part of a fairly well-known poem, [Brittle Beauty](https://www.luminarium.org/renlit/brittlebeauty.htm) (16th century):

> Brittle beauty, that Nature made so frail,
> Whereof the gift is small, and short the season;
> Flowering to-day, to-morrow apt to fail
> **Tickle treasure**, abhorred of reason :
> Dangerous to deal with, vain, of none avail
> Costly in keeping, past not worth two peason
> Slipper in sliding, as is an eel's tail
> Hard to obtain, once gotten, not geason
> Jewel of jeopardy, that peril doth assail
> False and untrue, enticed oft to treason
> Enemy to youth, that most may I bewail
> Ah ! bitter sweet, infecting as the poison
> Thou farest as fruit that with the frost is taken ;
> To-day ready ripe, tomorrow all to-shaken.

[The Folk-Speak of South Cheshire, 1887, contains a dictionary compiled by Thomas Darlington,](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Folk_speech_of_South_Cheshire/_6ETAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22tickell%20treasure%22%20meaning&pg=PA396&printsec=frontcover) which says that ‘tickle’ used to mean “sensitive, used of balances.” It quotes [Gascoigne](https://sourcetext.files.wordpress.com/2017/12/gascoigne_posies_1575.pdf), 1577:

> Vayne is the rest, and that most vayne of all,
> A smouldring smoke which flieth with every winde,
> A **tickell treasure**, like a trendlyng ball,
> A passing pleasure mocking but the minde,
> A fickle fee as fansie well can finde.
> A sommers fruite whiche long can never last,
> But ripeneth soone, and rottes againe as fast.

The line "slipper in sliding, as is an eel's tail" in the first poem, and the proximity to "fickle" in the second one both seem to imply a sense of treasure having a volatile nature, but I can't be sure that this is indeed the authors' intention.

So: Perhaps *treasure is tickle* means 'treasure/fortune is capricious and unpredictable'.

It's the best guess that I've got.

Comment: From onelook.com, Webster's 1828 dictionary, an adjective sense that fits:  https://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/tickle  TICK'LE, adjective **Tottering; wavering, or liable to waver and fall at the slightest touch; unstable; easily overthrown.** (sense marked as wholly obsolete in 1828.)